# База данных не добавляет строки

Tags: c#, sql, база-данных

Всем привет, есть такой код

```
static void Main()
    {
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=""c:\users\sergey\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\dbTrainee\dbTrainee\dbTest.mdf"";Integrated Security=True");
        SqlDataAdapter sqlDA = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from [Chat]", connection);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        sqlDA.Fill(ds);
        DataRow dr = ds.Tables[0].NewRow();
        dr["Name"] = "Sergey"; dr["Message"] = "One";
        DataRow dr1 = ds.Tables[0].NewRow();
        dr1["Name"] = "Inga"; dr1["Message"] = "Two";
        DataRow dr2 = ds.Tables[0].NewRow();
        dr2["Name"] = "Gena"; dr2["Message"] = "Three";
        ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(dr); ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(dr1); ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(dr2);        
        ds.AcceptChanges();
        SqlCommandBuilder sqlBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(sqlDA);
        sqlDA.Update(ds);
        DataTableReader d = ds.Tables[0].CreateDataReader();
        while (d.Read())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(d[1]);
        }      

    }
```

При первом запуске в БД добавляются 3 строки. При следующих нажатиях `ctrl+F5` новые (те же самые) строки не добавляются, не могу понять почему. Ведь компилятор проходит все те же самые инструкции. Почему так ?

Код из T-SQL

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Chat] (
    [ID]      INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Name]    NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    [Message] NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Table] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
);
```

Странно, если убрать `ds.AcceptChanges();` тогда работает как я и ожидаю. Почему ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сначала необходимо вызвать Update(), а уже потом AcceptChanges().

```
ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(dr); ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(dr1); ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(dr2);
        
        int result = sqlDA.Update(ds);
        ds.AcceptChanges();
        Console.WriteLine("Result="+result);
        DataTableReader d = ds.Tables[0].CreateDataReader();
        while (d.Read())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(d[1]);
        }
```

Твой вопрос подробнее описывается [здесь](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/spike/dataadapter-update-returns-0-and-doesnt-update-the-table-in-sql-server)

**EDIT:**
Также необходимо указать сами команды для адаптера, чтобы он знал, как ему выполнять запросы:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlCommandBuilder commandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(sqlDA);

        sqlDA.UpdateCommand = commandBuilder.GetUpdateCommand();
        sqlDA.InsertCommand = commandBuilder.GetInsertCommand();
```

Comment: Спасибо. Хочу уточнить, а разве сама команда `SqlCommandBuilder commandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(sqlDA);` не прописывает автоматом все команды в адаптере ?

Comment: Это можно увидеть если самому "продебажить" код. Сразу после создания все его команды равны null. Не знаю почему так. А вобще советую использовать Entity Framework. Хотя и там есть свой гемор.